# extracting a line of data from an excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to extract a line of data from a excel spreadsheet and transfer it to another sheet. I need to search for a series of dashes (- - - - -) and then extract the line of data that is 2 lines below the dashes.

Answer (score 0):

[Excel Find](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm)
Find syntax

Dim rFound As Range

Where "expression" is any valid range Object, e.g. Range("A1:A100"), Columns(2) etc. Also, a Range Object is returned whenever we use the Find Method.

expression.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)

Dim rFound As Range
     On Error Resume Next

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find(What:="- - - - -", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
             Match = rFound.Address
             MsgBox (rFound.Offset(2, 0))


        End If

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It can read data from Excel Tables.

I would build 2 Queries. The first would add an Index column (row number), then filter for the rows with dashes.  I would then add a simple calculated column: [Index] + 2.  This query does not need to output a table.

The second query would start from the base table, then Merge with the first query using that "[Index] + 2" column, and a Join Type of inner (only keep matches). This query would output a new table into Excel.

You could build almost all of this by just clicking around in the Power Query UI. The one formula needed would be very simple: `[Index] + 2`.